# Why is my Twilio status callback never called again even with a retry policy set to all?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm working with Twilio to send SMS messages and I'm trying to configure it so that it would retry the status callback request if the endpoint returns an error (500):

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

message = @client.messages.create(
  from: '+...',
  body: 'Test message',
  to: '+...
  status_callback: 'https://public-url/ack#rc=2&ct=1000&rp=all'
)
```

The endpoint I exposed always returns a 500 error, and I'm expecting Twilio to retry the endpoint 2 times. But this doesn't happen, it is never retrying the request.

Connection overrides are supposed to work with the message resource: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides

Why would this not work? Am I missing something or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding, `&sni=y`. I know with Ngrok, I need to do this, to see the retries.

[Connection Overrides](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides#connection-overrides)

Comment: I was also using Ngrok. That's weird. Thanks!